# How authentic is Ḥilyat al-awliyāʼ wa-ṭabaqāt al-aṣfiyāʼ Book by Abu Nu'aym al-Isfahani?

Tags: books

Ḥilyat al-awliyāʼ wa-ṭabaqāt al-aṣfiyāʼ
Book by Abu Nu'aym al-Isfahani

The Hilyat al-awliya' is a substantial work in ten volumes, comprising a total of 650 biographies, amounting to about 4,000 pages in the printed edition. The work includes many biographies of early Islam. **Most biographies of individuals that are directly involved with the development of Sufi mysticism are found in the tenth volume**.

Comment: What do you mean by authentic in the context of a book of biographies?

Comment: @Medi1Saif by authentic I mean that it should be from Prophet Muhammad (PBUH). It should not he fabrication and fake hadith.

Comment: How should that apply when a huge part of its content is not even about the prophet nor a hadith?

Comment: @Medi1Saif So about whom it is all about

Comment: @Medi1Saif actually I saw this hadith "one who knows himself, knows the almighty", when I search about this hadith I came across this book.

Comment: @Medi1Saif this book is used by Sufi to justify for their actions

Comment: Well the book actually is a reference for sunni sufi "culture" because it presents manners of people who might be regarded as examples of sufis, no matter if they claim to be sufis or not. It contains more than 4000 hadith and abu Nua'ym al-Isfahani is a hafidh of hadith (and I'd say a highly appreciated one too) and his book is a reference of some ahadith which can't be found elsewhere. It is a well appreciated and accepted book, by sufis and none sufis.

Comment: @Medi1Saif So is this book authentic. Based on your comments it seems to be authentic